# How to pass data to AddController to UITableViewController

Tags: swift

I have a problem with my swift code. I have an UITableViewCotroller with a prototype cell, in this cell there are three labels. I created the file **TimerCell.swift** with the @IBOutlet for the labels:

```
import UIKit

class TimerCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var circostanza: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var luogo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var tempo: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

and the file **TimerModel.swift** with this code:

```
import UIKit

 class TimerModel: NSObject, NSCoding {


var circostanza :String!
var luogo : String!
var tempo : String!


init(circostanzaIn:String, luogoIn:String, tempoIn:String) {
    circostanza = circostanzaIn
    luogo = luogoIn
    tempo = tempoIn
}

internal required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.circostanza = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("circostanza") as! String
    self.luogo = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("luogo") as! String
    self.tempo = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("tempo") as! String
    }

func encodeWithCoder(encoder: NSCoder) {
    encoder.encodeObject(self.circostanza, forKey: "circostanza")
    encoder.encodeObject(self.luogo, forKey: "luogo")
    encoder.encodeObject(self.tempo, forKey: "tempo")
}


}
```

Then I have a button + in the UITableViewCotroller to open an AddController with three text field to add some data. I want to save these data in the cell's labels. The code in the **AddController** is:

```
import UIKit

class AddTimerController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var fieldCircostanza: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var fieldLuogo: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var fieldTempo: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    fieldCircostanza.delegate = self
    fieldLuogo.delegate = self


    // 
    var keyboardToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44))
    keyboardToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent
    keyboardToolbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    keyboardToolbar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var flex = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    var save = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Fatto", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: fieldTempo, action: "resignFirstResponder")
    keyboardToolbar.setItems([flex, save], animated: false)
    fieldTempo.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar
}


func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder() // chiudere la tastiera nei campi di testo
    return true
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func annulla(sender: UIButton) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) // chiude una modal
}

@IBAction func salva(sender: UIButton) {
    if fieldCircostanza.text.isEmpty &&
        fieldLuogo.text.isEmpty &&
        fieldTempo.text.isEmpty{
            //alertView 
            return
    }

    var timer = TimerModel(circostanzaIn: fieldCircostanza.text,
        luogoIn: fieldLuogo.text,
        tempoIn: fieldTempo.text)


    DataManager.sharedInstance.salvaArray()
    DataManager.sharedInstance.detail.myCollection.reloadData()

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

Finally the **UITableViewCotroller** file:

```
import UIKit

class TimerViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return DataManager.sharedInstance.storage.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimerCell

    //cell.circostanza.text = timer.circostanza
    //cell.luogo.text = timer.luogo
    //cell.tempo.text = timer.tempo


    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {

        DataManager.sharedInstance.storage.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        DataManager.sharedInstance.salvaArray()

        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}

// MARK: - Navigazione

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "modifica" {
        //let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController).topViewController as AddController

    }
}


}
```

Can you help me with the code for saving data?

Comment: so, what error you are getting??

Comment: Hi, in the AddController when i click on the save button, the data that i have added in the text fields are not saved in the cell's labels on UITableViewController.

Comment: ok, so you are not getting any crash or error, just the values are not updating in the required labels??

Comment: Yes, i think that in UITableViewController miss some code to saving data, but i don't understand how to set it. I see only the prototype cell and when i try to add new data, nothing appears.

Comment: and this you have tested whether 
 - timer.circostanza
 - timer.luogo
 - timer.tempo

have values or not by printing in the tableViewController before assigning those values to cell labels

Comment: if i remove these comments:

 `//cell.circostanza.text = timer.circostanza
    //cell.luogo.text = timer.luogo
    //cell.tempo.text = timer.tempo`

in the **UITableViewCotroller** file, i have the error: **Use of unresolved identifier 'timer'**.

Comment: it seems logical, timer is not defined anywhere in this controller

Comment: ok, do you know what is the missing code to saving data?

Answer (score 0):

For accessing timer in tableViewController, do this:

```
import UIKit

class AddTimerController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var fieldCircostanza: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var fieldLuogo: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var fieldTempo: UITextField!

var timer: TimerModel! // Made timer a class member

override func viewDidLoad() {
    ......
}

// your code ....

@IBAction func salva(sender: UIButton) {
    if fieldCircostanza.text.isEmpty &&
        fieldLuogo.text.isEmpty &&
        fieldTempo.text.isEmpty{
            //alertView 
            return
    }

    timer = TimerModel(circostanzaIn: fieldCircostanza.text, // intialize timer
        luogoIn: fieldLuogo.text,
        tempoIn: fieldTempo.text)


    DataManager.sharedInstance.salvaArray()
    DataManager.sharedInstance.detail.myCollection.reloadData()

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

and after that in tableViewController, access it like this:

```
 class TimerViewController: UITableViewController {

    var timer: TimerModel! // Change to this

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       var controller : AddTimerController = AddTimerController()
       timer = controller.timer
    }

  // your code .......

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimerCell

        cell.circostanza.text = timer.circostanza
        cell.luogo.text = timer.luogo
        cell.tempo.text = timer.tempo

        return cell
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your availability, but now I have the error: **Cannot invoke initializer for type 'TimerModel' with no arguments** in TimerViewController file at line: `var timer: TimerModel = TimerModel()`

Comment: Hi, for that just provide init function in your timermodel

Answer (score 0):

for your query in the comment, this will correct that:

In your TimerModel:

```
  import UIKit

    class TimerModel: NSObject, NSCoding {


    var circostanza :String!
    var luogo : String!
    var tempo : String!


    override init() { // add this method
        super.init()
    }

    init(circostanzaIn:String, luogoIn:String, tempoIn:String) {
        circostanza = circostanzaIn
        luogo = luogoIn
        tempo = tempoIn
    }

    internal required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.circostanza = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("circostanza") as! String
        self.luogo = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("luogo") as! String
        self.tempo = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("tempo") as! String
        }

    func encodeWithCoder(encoder: NSCoder) {
        encoder.encodeObject(self.circostanza, forKey: "circostanza")
        encoder.encodeObject(self.luogo, forKey: "luogo")
        encoder.encodeObject(self.tempo, forKey: "tempo")
    }


    }
```

Comment: I have a crash, the line indicated is: `timer = controller.timer` in TimerViewController file

Comment: In timerViewController, change the line var timer: TimerModel = TimerModel() to var timer: TimerModel! , also edited in my answer

Comment: Ok sorry, but in this way I have a crash, see the screen please: http://d.pr/i/12qDU

Comment: HI, if possible can you send the whole project. then it will be easy to debug....

Comment: Hi, here a link of a similar exercise: http://d.pr/f/19iY2

I don't understand how to set the code to have a new TableView when i click on the button in the label in DetailViewCotroller. At click i have a crash.

Comment: Downloaded and ran your project, able to reproduce that error that you are talking about, will look into this....

Comment: The error is not the same, but the aim is the same. I have tried with another project to learn and to understand what is wrong. I want to create another TableView when i click on a button in a DetailViewController and also to add data to this table. I don't know how to set code for this, can you help me?

Comment: HI, on clicking that Button what you are actually want to do, not able to understand .. Explain with the reference of your app in detail

Comment: On clicking the button there is the segue to ListTherapyController with the UITableView. In this controller on clicking add button there is the segue to AddTherapyController for add some data, i want to save this data in the ListTherapyController's cell and also in TherapyViewController.